# How to add an update to App Store app(Stuck)?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I have uploaded my app through `xcode` and then added a it for testing but I'm not able to understand how to move ahead.
[image: Stuck at this phase]
It has been quiet many days since I uploaded and I thought the subsequent steps will be automatic but I'm not able to see if Update has been done.

Here is my first app Uploaded which is showing ready for sale but I'm not able to get my later builds that I've uploaded here.

[image: Not able to see in here]

Here are list of my uploads with Ready for sale in 1st upload but nothing in my second upload.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was missing at a silly part as most of the tutorial I saw were showing old UI and not clearly mentioning.All I had to do was to click here.On + version or platform and then add my new build.
[image: Click here and on IOS]

And then save and submit to review